# ESlint ignores directories when called from npm script

Tags: npm, eslint

In my package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {                            
       "lint": "eslint --debug components"   
}
```

When I run it with `npm run lint` I see this

```
> eslint --debug components
eslint:cli Running on files +0ms
eslint:glob-util Creating list of files to process. +39ms
eslint:ignored-paths Looking for ignore file in c:\dev\Monies +6ms
eslint:ignored-paths Could not find ignore file in cwd +1ms
eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 13ms +5ms
```

So it ignores my dir.

It does work as expected when I run it from command line.

```
node_modules\.bin\eslint --debug compoments

eslint:cli Running on files +0ms
eslint:glob-util Creating list of files to process. +39ms
eslint:ignored-paths Looking for ignore file in c:\dev\Monies +5ms
eslint:ignored-paths Could not find ignore file in cwd +1ms
eslint:cli-engine Processing c:\dev\Monies\compoments\Header.js +15ms
eslint:cli-engine Linting c:\dev\Monies\compoments\Header.js +2ms
eslint:config Constructing config for c:\dev\Monies\compoments\Header.js +1ms
```

Why it doesn't work with `npm run`?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with npm 3.10.8 and eslint 3.8.1. It works, for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in the directory name:

```
eslint --debug components
```

versus

```
node_modules\.bin\eslint --debug compoments
```

compo**n**ents != compo**m**ents

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how much more time I would lose before noticing it :)